# Get a picture from the message

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

I need to get a picture from the message if it is there
I use rewritten version

I tried this:

```
message.attachments[0]['url']
```

But getting an error

```
    Ignoring exception in on_message
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\vlad0\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\discord\client.py", line 227, in _run_event
    await coro(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\Users\vlad0\Desktop\bot\bot.py", line 121, in on_message
    print(message.attachments[0]['url'])
TypeError: 'Attachment' object is not subscriptable
```

If you leave only the index or only attachments, you get this:

```
<discord.message.Attachment object at 0x00000228B8E3BE80>
```

How can i get image url?

Comment: Evidently `[]` is not the correct way to get information from an Attachment object. Perhaps you should check its properties instead.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can directly get the url property from the object

```
message.attachments[0].url
```

Basically, what the error says is that this object does not implement the `__getitem__`, which means you can't use `[i]` on it.