# How do I make a uploaded image through text be embeded by a bot and upload it to a different channel

Tags: discord, discord.py

So i'm fairly new here and i'm struggling with this part. so I have a command right that is called !alert. so for example !alert hello world, This will alert to all the channels/servers my bot is into. But what I want to do is !alert (drag image) and instead of alerting all the channels/servers my bot is into with a text. it will be with an image that I drag and uploaded through the !alert

````
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def waw(ctx, *, msg): #COMMAND NAME
    for guild in client.guilds:
        role = get(guild.roles, name = 'Wafaduck Alerts')
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if(channel.name == 'wafaduck-alerts'):   
                await channel.send(f"{role.mention}")```
````

Comment: Does this help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55206958/get-a-picture-from-the-message?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can look at the Discord API **[here](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Message.attachments)** for more information.
However, this code worked for me:

```py
@commands.command(name = "alert")
@commands.has_permissions(administrator=True)
async def waw(ctx): 
    for guild in client.guilds:
        role = get(guild.roles, name = 'Wafaduck Alerts')
        for channel in guild.channels:
            if(channel.name == 'wafaduck-alerts'):
                #Simplified for example purposes   
                embed=discord.Embed(title = "Image: ")  
                embed.set_image(url=ctx.message.attachments[0].url)
                await channel.send(f"{role.mention}")                 
                await channel.send(embed=embed)
```